# Change page content according to url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a backend that handles requests like

```
http://mysite/A.html // return A.html
http://mysite/B.html // return B.html
http://mysite/C.html // return C.html
```

Now I need to add site menu to visit A,B,C pages from it without page reloading.
And If I load page A.html, then click on B in the menu, page B should be displayed and url becomes http://mysite/A.html#B.

So I need somehow write code to allow user to make such requests:

```
 http://mysite/A.html // show A.html
 //...same for B.html, C.html
 http://mysite/A.html#B // show B.html
 http://mysite/C.html#A // show A.html
 //...etc
```

As far as I know PHP backend can't handle # in the url, so I need to use Js.
So guys, any ideas here?

Currently If I handle request 
`http://mysite/A.html#B`, I load A.html from PHP backend then manually replace page content with B.html using JQuery.

**PS:** My current method shows page A.html for a sec before replacing itself to B.html which is bad for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery Ajax GET method to return the HTML contents of another page.

**jQuery**

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var ID = $(this).attr('href');
$.get(ID, function(data) {
$('#MyReturnDiv').html(data);
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="directory of return/A.html">A</a>
<a href="directory of return/B.html">B</a>
<a href="directory of return/C.html">C</a>

<div id="MyReturnDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, kinda no problems with getting HTML using JQuery AJAX. Main problem is how to handle request `A.html#B`. So backend returns A.html and I need to display B.html **without** showing page A.html. (I know 2 ways: redirecting(bad for me), making html initially `display: none` and show only desired html.